# problem in crowdfunding contract: ParserError: Expected primary expression

Tags: smartcontracts

I am with a code but I have this problem:

ParserError: Expected primary expression. --> contracts/Crowfunding.sol/crowfundingstampe.sol:35:2: | 35 | } | ^

the code is:

```
> SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.8;

contract Crowfunding {
    uint256 public fundingGoal; //the target amount of funds that must be raised for the campaign to be considered successful
    uint256 public deadline; // the deadline by which contributions must be received
    uint256 public amountRaised; // the total amount of funds raised so far
    mapping (address => uint256) public contributions; // tracks the amount contributed by each individual.
    address [] public suppliers; //an array that keeps track of the addresses of all suppliers who have contributed to the campaign
    bool public funded;
    uint256 public fundsReturned;

constructor(uint256 _fundingGoal, uint256 _deadline) public {
    fundingGoal = _fundingGoal;
    deadline = _deadline;

    }

function contribute() public payable {
    require(msg.value > 0, "You must contribute a positive amount.");
    require(now <= deadline, "The deadline for contributions has passed.");

    contributions[msg.sender] += msg.value;
    amountRaised += msg.value;
    backers.push(msg.sender);

    }

function returnFunds() public {
    require(now > deadline, "The deadline for contributions has not passed yet.");
    require(fundsReturned == 0, "The funds have already been returned.");

  for (uint256 i = 0; i < backers.length; i++) {
    backers[i].transfer(contributions[backers[i]]);
}
>
```

to compile but it pop o that error

Answer (score 0):

First of all was missing array backers, two brackets } , keyword now deprecated, instead use block.timestamp, and in for() loop backers[i] must be payable.

// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.17;

contract Crowfunding {
uint256 public fundingGoal; //the target amount of funds that must be raised for 
the campaign to be considered successful
uint256 public deadline; // the deadline by which contributions must be received
uint256 public amountRaised; // the total amount of funds raised so far
mapping (address => uint256) public contributions; // tracks the amount 
contributed by each individual.
address [] public suppliers; //an array that keeps track of the addresses of all 
suppliers who have contributed to the campaign
bool public funded;
uint256 public fundsReturned;
address[] public backers;

constructor(uint256 _fundingGoal, uint256 _deadline) {
fundingGoal = _fundingGoal;
deadline = _deadline;
}

function contribute() public payable {
    require(msg.value > 0, "You must contribute a positive amount.");
    require(block.timestamp <= deadline, "The deadline for contributions has 
passed.");
    contributions[msg.sender] += msg.value;
    amountRaised += msg.value;
    backers.push(msg.sender);
}

function returnFunds() public {
    require(block.timestamp > deadline, "The deadline for contributions has not 
passed yet.");
    require(fundsReturned == 0, "The funds have already been returned.");
    for (uint256 i = 0; i < backers.length; i++) {
    payable(backers[i]).transfer(contributions[backers[i]]);
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Still having a problem with the last part: function returnFunds() public {
    require(block.timestamp>deadline, "The deadline for contributions has not passed yet.");
    require(fundsReturned == 0, "The funds have already been returned.");
    for (uint256 i = 0; i < backers.length; i++) {
    payable(backers[i]).transfer(contributions[backers[i]]);
    }
}    ParserError: Expected '(' but got identifier

Comment: You compiling contract using remix ?

Comment: I mean i compiled code in remix, after in vscode and works good, no errors, are you sure you copied it properly ?

Comment: yes! thanks. I need it to set a new variable. Thanks for your help! it's my first smart contract.

Comment: Good luck with your studying!